# what does ":" mean in this case in coffee script?

Tags: coffeescript

I am new to coffee script. When I am looking at this document https://atom.io/docs/api/v0.198.0/CommandRegistry#instance-add
I see a code segment like,

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
  'user:insert-date': (event) ->
    editor = @getModel()
    editor.insertText(new Date().toLocaleString())
```

while the function signature looks,

```
::add(target, commandName, callback)
```

So in the code segment, what does `:` on the second line mean? My understanding is the 'user:insert-date' before `:` is `commandName` in the signature. The thing after `:` is "callback". So `:` is a argument separator like a `,`? I don't find this introduced in the coffee script document http://coffeescript.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending mu is too short's answer (the user is absolutely correct that the second parameter `commandName`can be an object without the explicit braces {})

Atom's sourcecode:
https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/v0.198.0/src/command-registry.coffee#L81

```
add: (target, commandName, callback) ->
if typeof commandName is 'object'
  commands = commandName
  disposable = new CompositeDisposable
  for commandName, callback of commands
    disposable.add @add(target, commandName, callback)
  return disposable
```

Answer (score 3):

That colon is just part of an object literal. The braces around object literals are optional in CoffeeScript when there's no ambiguity. If we add the optional braces, we get something that looks more like JavaScript:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor', {
  'user:insert-date': (event) ->
    #...
}
```

So `atom.commands.add` is being called with two arguments. The first is the string `'atom-text-editor'` and the second is an object with one key (`'user:insert-date'`) whose value is an anonymous function that takes a single argument.